# determinant of multiple Matrices -question from an old exam-

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

[image]

translation from Hebrew:
let $A=(a_{ij})_{n\cdot n}$ prove that the determinants of the following matrices is as follows: $(u_1+u_2+...+u_n)det(A)$.
I proposed using the additive property of the determinant, my friend corrected me and said that isn't possible due to the fact that every pair of matrices has 2 different rows from each other...
thanks for helping!

Comment: Hint:
$$
\left\vert\begin{matrix}ua&vb\\ c&d\end{matrix}\right\vert
+\left\vert\begin{matrix}a&b\\ uc&ud\end{matrix}\right\vert
=\left\vert\begin{matrix}ua&b\\ uc&d\end{matrix}\right\vert
+\left\vert\begin{matrix}a&vb\\ c&vd\end{matrix}\right\vert.
$$

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: thanks shaun!
since i have learned mathJax